# Cannot ping/access single host over VPN

Tags: vlan, ipv4, network, vpn

I am running openVPN server on pfSense machine, which is also the router of the network. This network has several VLAN's, where only single one of them is of interest - 10.0.100.0/22.
The openVPN tunnel network uses 10.0.101.0/24 and all Rules are set accordingly. In my case, I have machine A (10.0.100.2, linux), machine B (10.0.100.3) running Windows and machine **C** (10.0.100.4), running also linux. When I establish a VPN connection using machine D (Windows, externally), I get IP 10.0.101.2.

What I **CAN** do:

- Ping/SSH A from D
- Ping B from D
- Ping **C** from A
- Ping/SSH C from B
- Access router from D (trough 10.0.100.1)

What I **CAN'T** do:

- Ping/SSH **C** from D
- Ping D from **C**

P.S.
When pinging **C** from D, running  *tcpdump arp* on C, I can see an ARP request: Who has D, tell **C**, but with no response. Why wouldn't pfsense tell the location of D?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full router configuration. Also, remember that your `10.0.100.0/22` network includes `10.0.101.0/24`, and routers route packets between networks, not from a network back to the same network. If the problem is a host configuration problem, we cannot help with that.

Comment: @RonMaupin No, this is not the case. Yes they are the same network, but the subnetwork 10.0.101.0/24 can be seen as a separate VLAN for the following reasons:
- The subnet of host D is /24
- In the pfsense router, I have a rule which allows traffic from my VPN network to 10.0.100.0/22 and it is clearly visible that traffic passes trough it. It cannot be host configuration, as connecting machine D directly on the network can perfectly access host C. I dont know what configuration I could add

Answer (score 1):

The ARP attempt is the giveaway:

> ... several VLAN's, where only single one of them is of interest -
> 10.0.100.0/22 ...
>
> ... openVPN tunnel network uses 10.0.101.0/24 ...

Those two networks overlap, so routing is compromised. If you NAT the OpenVPN clients then connections from VPN clients to LAN hosts may work but there's no way to get the reverse to work.

- Change the subnet prefixes so there's no overlap.
- Remove the NAT option from OpenVPN and route the client subnet properly.

Comment: No, this does not apply to my case as pfSense forces you to have the subnet of your VPN tunnel (TUN) network in the same range as in your LAN (VLAN in my case) and otherwise it is not possible

Comment: TUN is a layer-3 interface that's routed (possibly by default using NAT). TAP is a layer-2 interface that's bridged. It's *highly* recommended to use a routed tunnel with a TUN interface. It seems you're mixing things so they can't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using (TUN) tunnel VPN, which does not employ ARP protocol. Switching to TAP (which uses Layer 2) enables ARP protocol (and much more) and resolves all the aforementioned issues.

Comment: Tun and Tap are Linux (off-topic here) things. What goes on inside a host is off-topic, and the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support, but the Linux Foundation does not offer that.